# Return indices of all matching nested sub-lists within a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, recursion, nested, sublist

Given a list with many possible sub-lists which are nested to an arbitrary depth and have a variable number of elements, is there a way to return the indices of all the instances of all sub-lists which meet certain criteria?

For example:

```
list1 = [1, 4, 7, ["a", "h", "b"], 2]
list2 = [1, 4, 7, "x", "g", ["a", 5, 8, "p", "b"], 2, 4, 7, "k", 9]
list3 = [1, 4, 7, ["a", "z", ["a", 6, "b"], "b"], 5, 3]
list4 = [1, 4, 7, ["a", "b", "c"], 3, 4]

sublist_function(list1, {[0]:'a', [-1]: 'b'}) 
# should return [[3]] (One instance of a matching sub-list (whose 0th element is 'a' and whose last element is 'b') found at list1[3])
sublist_function(list2, {[0]:'a', [-1]: 'b'}) 
# should return [[5]] (One instance of a matching sub-list, found at list2[5])
sublist_function(list3, {[0]:'a', [-1]: 'b'}) 
# should return [[3], [3][2]] (Two instances of a matching sub-list, found at list3[3] and list3[3][2])
sublist_function(list4, {[0]:'a', [-1]: 'b'}) 
# should return [] (There are no instances of a matching sub-list in list4)
```

I thought it would be a simple matter to adjust a function's code that tests for the presence/absence of the sub-list into one that would return the indices of the sub-lists, but this is proving to be quite a challenge for a beginning programmer like myself. The original function's code can be found in an answer to a previous question of mine from @AdamSmith, [Find generic sub-lists within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460277/find-generic-sub-lists-within-a-list)

UPDATE: Using [How to find the number of nested lists in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877186/how-to-find-the-number-of-nested-lists-in-a-list) as a guide, the following is the best I have been able to come up with so far, though 1) it only returns the LAST index of each matching sub-list and 2) replaces the last index of a matching sub-list with the last index of the first-occurring identical sub-list. I'm not even concerned that it doesn't have an argument to specify which characteristics of a list to match, but instead defines it within the function itself - that's icing on the cake at this point:

```
def sublist_function(lst, ind=None):
    if ind is None:
        ind = []
    for el in lst:
        if isinstance(el, list) and el[0] == 'a' and el[-1] == 'b':
            ind.append([lst.index(el)])
            sublist_function(el, ind)
        elif isinstance(el, list):
            sublist_function(el, ind)
    return ind

list3 = [1, 4, 7, ["a", "z", ["a", 6, "b"], "b"], 5, 3]
print(sublist_function(list3)) #should return '[[3], [3][2]]'
>> [[3], [2]]

list5 = [1, 4, ["a", 5, "b"], 3, 4, 6, ["a", 5, "b"], 5]
print(sublist_function(list5)) #identical sub-lists (should return [[2], [6]])
>> [[2], [2]]

list6 = [1, 4, ["a", 7, "b"], 3, 4, 6, ["a", 5, "b"], 5]
print(sublist_function(list6)) #unique sub-lists (correctly returns [[2], [6]])
>> [[2], [6]]
```

Comment: why do you need the number of occurrences if your return value is a list of their locations? Couldn't you detect how many there are by getting the `len` of the return result?

Comment: you cannot use notation like `sblst[0] == 'a'` in an argument because it will be evaluated and likely return just `True` or `False` to the function.  Instead you need some valid value to indicate the relationship - I'd think a mapping of `{indice:expected_value}` pairs would make a lot of sense.

Comment: or use a basic function to evaluate the check: `def check(sublst): return sblst[0] == 'a' and sblst[-1] == 'b'` although since this is "variable depth" nested structure you will probably need error checking for cases of non-list entries.