# discover how many lists are inside a value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key-value-store

```
my_dict = {"fruits": ["apple", "orange", "grape", "maracuya", "pineapple"],
           "countries": [["India", "China", "Brazil", "Lesotho", "Nepal"], 
                         ["Spain", "Italy", "Japan", "Indonesia", "Russia"], 
                         ["Germany", "Austria", "Paraguay", "New Zealand", "Peru"],
                         ["Australia", "Colombia", "Belice", "Swaziland"]],
           "colors": [["blue", "black", "green", "yellow", "red"],
                      ["purple", "pink", "white", "lila"]]}
```

Is there a way to know how many lists I have under each key? for example: under the key "fruits" I just have one, under "countries" I have 4

what I've tried it was mostly:

```
for key, values in my_dict.items():
    print(len(values))
```

which didn't work

```
for key in my_dict.values():
   print(len(key))
```

also failed

Comment: I believe there are 4 lists under 'Country' (or 5, if the outer list is included). Please clarify. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was 4 in the case of countries. I've already added some more info :-)

Answer (score 1):

One approach, although it doesn't feel very pythonic, is to just loop through the values and, if a value is a list, test each item in the list to see whether *it* is a list, keeping count of the ones that are:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    count = 0
    if isinstance(value, list):
        for val in value:
            if isinstance(val, list):
                count += 1
        print(f'{key} has {count} lists')
```

Prints:

```
fruits has 0 list
countries has 4 lists
colors has 2 lists
```

Comment: This solution assumes a nested list will only contain lists. What it will fail for `{foo:[bar, [baz], [qux]]}`

Comment: @XeroSmith Right you are! Updated and works on your example. Could probably be made more elegant, but I feel this is illustrative.

Comment: you have my upvote, your update is the answer I would've posted more or less. I believe illustrative answers are better than clever answers especially for beginers. Now if the OP wants to add the outer list they can simply simply start the increment the counter when it is encountered before iterating over the list. And you might want to change `v` to value in `if isinstance(v, list)` so it matches the `value` at the start of the dictionary iteration. You have my upvote

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877186/how-to-find-the-number-of-nested-lists-in-a-list).

Comment: @DYZ ooo, recursive solution for nested lists. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

My first question would be if you might want to put the list of fruits in another list too. Then the structure is the same for all your cases and the solution is simply:

```
{key: len(value) for key, value in my_dict.items()}
```

Otherwise, if you want to stick to that data structure you posted you can do:

```
{key: len(value) if isinstance(value[0], list) else 1 for key, value in my_dict.items()}
```

This would result in:

```
{'colors': 2, 'countries': 4, 'fruits': 1}
```

I must admit that there are quite some assumptions in this solution. If you want to find all lists in any place, that would make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot codingpoets, your answer was the most suitable one

Thanks also to all the rest of the people who read my problem and tried to help :-)